# Automating VPN switching

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, vpn

I can us a VPN app like tunnelbear to appear to be in other countries, but is there a way to do this in a bash script or applescript?

I want to be able to run automated tests on my iOS apps (in the simulator) and change the apparent country.